# MYSQL PHP JSON not returning expected results

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to build a page for users to add work orders to a project. If the project already exists in the database, any work orders related to it will be listed in a side display. I want new work order numbers to be allocated automatically either based on querying for the last allocated number for the selected project or if the first work order on the project, a new number prefixed with '-01'.

Unfortunately, I'm having no joy with the first work order on the project whereas if I run the SQL directly in PHP MyAdmin, I get the result I expect.

Your assistance will be much appreciated. My code is shared below:

HTML:

```
 <?php
    include 'core/init.php';
    protect_page();
    include 'includes/overall/header.php';  
    //get all project types data
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY proj_nbr";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    //get all project managers' data
    $sql_staff = "SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY staff_number";
    $result_staff = mysqli_query($connect,$sql_staff);
    $rowCount_staff = mysqli_num_rows($result_staff);

    //generate new work order number
    $sql_wo_nbr = "SELECT MAX(wo_nbr) as wo_nbr FROM workorders ";
    $result_wo_nbr = mysqli_query($connect,$sql_wo_nbr);
    $rowCount_wo_nbr = mysqli_num_rows($result_wo_nbr); 
    ?>
<div class="welcome-headers">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <h2>Add New Work Order</h2>
</div>
<br>
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['success'])){
    $msg = $_GET['success'];
    echo $msg;
} else {

}
?>
<div class="forms-add">
<form action="add_workorders.php" method="POST">
    <label class="labels-unedit">Work Order Number (Auto-generated):</label>
    <input class="inputs-unedit" type="text" id="wo_nbr" name="wo_nbr"size="8"maxlength="8" value = "" readonly>    


    <!-- <input type="text" id="pj_nbr_hidden" name="pj_nbr_hidden"> -->

    <br><br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Project Details</legend>
        <label>Project Number:</label>
        <select  class= "selects" id="proj_nbr" name="proj_nbr" required onchange="getNewWoAndDates(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select a project </option>
                <?php       
                    //echo "Total number of records found: <strong>$rowCount</strong>."; 
                    if($rowCount>0){
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                            echo '<option value="'.
                                $row['proj_id'].'">'.
                                $row['proj_nbr'].
                                ' - '.
                                $row['proj_desc'].
                                ' </option>';                
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo '<option value="">Project not available</option>';
                    }           
                ?>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <label>Start Date:</label>
        <input class="inputs" type="text" id="proj_start_date" name="proj_start_date"size="8"maxlength="8" value = "" readonly>
        <br><br>
        <label>End Date:</label>
        <input class="inputs" type="text" id="proj_end_date" name="proj_end_date"size="8"maxlength="8" value = "" readonly>
    </fieldset>
    <br><br>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Work Order Details:</legend>
        <label>Description:</label>
        <input class="inputs" type="text" id="wo_desc" name="wo_desc"size="50"maxlength="50" required autocomplete="off">
        <br><br>
        <label>Manager:</label>
        <select class="selects" id="wo_mgr_id" name="wo_mgr_id">
            <option value="">Select a manager</option>
                <?php       
                    //echo "Total number of records found: <strong>$rowCount</strong>."; 
                    if($rowCount_staff>0){
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_staff)){
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['staff_id'].'">'.
                            $row['staff_number'].
                            ' - '.$row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'].         
                            ' </option>';                
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo '<option value="">Staff not available</option>';
                    }           
                ?>  
        </select>
    </fieldset>
        <br><br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Work Order Duration:</legend>
        <label>Start Date:</label>
        <input class="inputs" type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date" required>
        <br><br>
        <label>End Date:</label>
        <input class="inputs" type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date" required >
    </fieldset>
    <br><br>

    <button class="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit" >Save Work Order</button>
</form>
</div>

<div class="side_display" id= "wo_display">
No work orders to display for the selected project.
</div>

</body>
<br><br>
<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Javascript:

```
function getNewWoAndDates()
{
    var id = $("#proj_nbr").val();
    //alert(id);
    if (id != '')
    {
        $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: "get_proj_nbrs2.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: { theid : id }, //data to SEND to PHP file
            dataType: "JSON",

            success: function(result) 
            {
                console.log(result); //returns NULLs instead of actual values

                $('#wo_nbr').val(result[0].wo_nbr_new);
                $('#proj_start_date').val(result[0].proj_start_date);
                $('#proj_end_date').val(result[0].proj_end_date);

                //Below code to populate the side display:
                var wo_count = result[1].length;
                var myDiv = document.getElementById("wo_display");
                if (wo_count>0)
                {
                    myDiv.innerHTML = "<table id='newTable'><tr><th>Work Order Number</th><th>Work Order Description</th></tr></table>";
                    var myTable = document.getElementById("newTable");
                    for (i=1; i<=wo_count;i++)
                    {
                        var myRow = myTable.insertRow(i);

                        var myCell1 = myRow.insertCell(0);
                        var myCell2 = myRow.insertCell(1);

                        myCell1.innerHTML = result[1][i-1].wo_nbr;
                        myCell2.innerHTML = result[1][i-1].wo_desc;                     
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    myDiv.innerHTML = "There are no work orders to display for the selected project.";
                }
            }
        });
    }else
    {
        alert("Please select a Project Number");
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

include 'connect_db.php';

if (isset($_POST['theid']) && !empty($_POST['theid']))
{
    $new_wo = array();
    $result = array();
    $workorders = array();
    $sql2 = "SELECT p.proj_nbr as wo_proj_nbr,p.start_date as proj_start_date,p.end_date as proj_end_date, MAX(w.wo_nbr) AS wo_nbr,
                CASE 
                WHEN SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1 <= 9 THEN CONCAT(p.proj_nbr,'-0',SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1)
                WHEN SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1 > 9 THEN CONCAT(p.proj_nbr,'-',SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1)
                WHEN w.wo_nbr IS NULL THEN CONCAT(p.proj_nbr,'-','01')
                ELSE 'No Work Order'
                END AS wo_nbr_new
                FROM workorders as w 
                INNER JOIN projects as p on p.proj_id = w.proj_id
                WHERE w.proj_id = '".$_POST['theid']."'";
    if($result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2)){
        $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
        {           
            $output['proj_start_date'] = $row['proj_start_date'];
            $output['proj_end_date'] = $row['proj_end_date'];                       
            $output['wo_nbr_new'] = $row['wo_nbr_new'];
            array_push($new_wo,$output);
        }
    }

    $sql_wo = "SELECT p.proj_nbr, p.proj_desc, w.wo_nbr, w.wo_desc 
                FROM workorders AS w
                LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON w.proj_id = p.proj_id
                WHERE w.proj_id = '".$_POST['theid']."'
                ORDER BY w.proj_id, w.wo_nbr";
    if($result_wo = mysqli_query($connect,$sql_wo)){
        $rowCount_wo = mysqli_num_rows($result_wo);

        //show work orders available for the selected project
        while($rowx=mysqli_fetch_array($result_wo))
        {
            $wo_added = array('wo_nbr'=>$rowx['wo_nbr'],'wo_desc' => $rowx['wo_desc']);
            array_push($workorders,$wo_added);
        }
    }
    array_push($result,$new_wo);
    array_push($result,$workorders);
    echo json_encode($result);
}   

?>
```

Comment: Don't put data directly into SQL queries. Use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Comment noted Peter. Could that be a contributing factor to the issue I'm facing?

Comment: It is an issue for sure. If it causes your problem I don't know.

Comment: I thought it is a risk re SQL injection in a production environment but whilst in development, it's ok. Also, the json_encode returns results for existing work orders but not for the first work order being added on a project.

Comment: There is simply no reason not to use parameterized queries. It's safer (in terms of datatypes), more secure, reads better, and faster if you execute queries repeatedly.